# In Highcharts, zooming a small selection up to the edge, zooms both x and y when zoomtype = x

Tags: javascript, highcharts, zooming

I'm creating a bubble graph that has an x-axis over a period of time. The bubbles are populated based on y-axis and sized based on the z value in the graph data.

The graph loads and renders as expected.

I have two sets of data. One set has all the data points that are returned from a query in our system. The second data set (which is the default upon loading the graph) has a smaller number of items that make up the largest 45 items (based on the z value).

When the user zooms into a section of the full graph, the selection event will change the data set to the larger, full set of data so that any points that were previously hidden in the default data set will be exposed. This is working perfectly as expected.

**Here's the problem though:**

When the user attempts to zoom in on a small selection of the chart, starting from just near the edge and moving to the edge, especially if there's only a single bubble in the selection, the graph will zoom both X AND Y, not just X. I have zoomtype set to 'x' and if you zoom the center of the chart, it will only zoom in on the x axis. The y axis remains fixed.

Here is the chart code from jsfiddle (data sets are in the jsfiddle link below):

```
(function() {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        global: {
            useUTC: true,
            timezoneOffset: 480         },
        lang: {
            contextButtonTitle: 'Chart Download and Print',
        }
    });

    $('#visual_1').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bubble',
            zoomType: 'x',
            height: 400,
            events: {
                selection: function(event) {
                    if (typeof event.xAxis !== "undefined") {
                        if (event.xAxis[0].min > event.xAxis[0].axis.dataMin ||
                            event.xAxis[0].max < event.xAxis[0].axis.dataMax) {
                                var bigChart = $('#visual_1').highcharts();
                                bigChart.series[0].setData(zoomChartData);
                                bigChart.yAxis[0] = orgChartYaxis;
                        }
                    } else {
                        var bigChart = $('#visual_1').highcharts();
                        bigChart.series[0].setData(graphData);
                    }
                }
            },
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            useHTML: true,
            text: 'Influence last 52 weeks'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
                month: '%b %e',
                year: '%b'
            },
            title: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                enabled: false
            },
            startOnTick: false,
            endOnTick: false,
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            gridLineColor: '#DDDDDD',
            gridLineDashStyle: 'ShortDot',
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '{point.label}',
                    allowOverlap: false,
                    crop: false,
                    overflow: 'none'
                }
            },
            bubble: {
                minSize: 8,
                maxSize: 100
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: graphData
        }]
    });
})();
```

Here is the jsfiddle to this problem: https://jsfiddle.net/emergingdzns/8dfuga09/

See the screenshots below where I show you in the jsfiddle how to replicate this issue.

[image: Where to zoom example]
[image: Results of zoom to edge]

Comment: The problem is fixed on github master branch of Highcharts - more info: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5471

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to this problem is to set a `minRange` for your x-axis (see http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.minRange). What this will do is force the absolute smallest interval a user can zoom to.

For your fiddle, I added the following to the x-axis:

```
minRange: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
```

This will allow the user to zoom in until there are only seven days visible on the chart (for example, 10. Sep to 16. Sep). You can set this to any value you like to get you as granular as you need, and should hopefully help resolve the issue where your bubbles are "falling" off the chart.

Here's my revision: https://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/8dfuga09/2/

Comment: The problem from question can still be replicated in your demo when zooming to small zone on right side of the chart.

Comment: @KacperMadej You're right ... what would you suggest? Perhaps a larger `minRange` value, such as two weeks (14 days) or one month (30 days)?

Comment: I just found this. The problem is fixed on github master branch of Highcharts - more info: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5471

Comment: @KacperMadej Gorgeous! Thank you all so very much for finding and resolving issues like this via questions on Stack Overflow.